# fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.0 404 (Not Found) - CSS- Angular - localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, localhost

Could someone tell me how to resolve this below errors?
I have download template from internet. tried to converting into angular 2 components. everything is okay, i can able to see the app running in my machine under localhost:4200. but i don't know why the following errors coming and **no icons loading in app**

in my **index.html** am having following url

```
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' >
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" >
```

in my **meterialize.css**

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Roboto";
    src:local(Roboto Thin), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.eot?#iefix") 
    format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff2") format("woff2"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf") format("truetype");font-weight:200;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Roboto";
    src:local(Roboto Light), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2") format("woff2"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:300;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Roboto";
    src:local(Roboto Regular), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:400;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Roboto";
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
     url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
     font-weight:500;
    }
@font-face{
    font-family:"Roboto";
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff2") format("woff2"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:700;
}
@font-face{
font-family:"Material-Design-Icons";
src:url("../fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.eot?#iefix") 
format("embedded-opentype"), 
url("../fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff2") format("woff2"), 
url("../fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.woff") format("woff"), 
url("../fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.ttf") format("truetype"), 
url("../fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg#Material-Design-Icons") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

**console error**

```
materialize.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.0 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
materialize.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ materialize.min.js:6
core.js:3688 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
about:106 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.0 404 (Not Found)
about:106 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff 404 (Not Found)
about.component.ts:19 about {basicInfo: Array(1), exp: Array(1), prog_skills: Array(1), otherSkAndDevTools: Array(1), socialNwrk: Array(1)}
about:106 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf 404 (Not Found)
aos.min.js:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff2 404 (Not Found)
o @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
O @ aos.min.js:1
S @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ custom-script.js:1
j @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
I @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
aos.min.js:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff2 404 (Not Found)
o @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
O @ aos.min.js:1
S @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ custom-script.js:1
j @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
I @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
aos.min.js:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 404 (Not Found)
o @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ aos.min.js:1
r @ aos.min.js:1
O @ aos.min.js:1
S @ aos.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ custom-script.js:1
j @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
I @ jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.woff 404 (Not Found)
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.woff 404 (Not Found)
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0 404 (Not Found)
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf 404 (Not Found)
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf 404 (Not Found)
about:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0 404 (Not Found)
```

i tried all possible solution from SO, but nothing helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I've resolved this after download the required dep files from github and put it in asset folder

Answer (score 3):

It is returning 404 error (Not found) for all fonts imported in CSS, you have to decide if you're going to use:

- Fonts from Google: imported in your HTML file.
- Fonts from local path, in project: defined in your CSS file.

You can combine them but you're showing both options, you need to decide it so that we can fix it.

Check if first URL in error: http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.0][1](http://localhost:4200/assets/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.0) downloads a file or also returns error.

Probably the problem is with the path defined in CSS file, eg `src:url("../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Medium.eot");`.

Comment: thank your for your kind response @Ignacio. am actually fixed my issue. and your suggestions is also valid solution. i did some silly things. instead of using CDN's i directly download dependency files form github and put it in my workspace that resolved everything

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio   that's the right solution